# set thread affinity in a linux kernel module

Tags: kernel-module, setthreadaffinitymask

as most C programmers know libc gives a non portable functions for thread cpu affinity tuning (pthread_attr_setaffinity_np()). However, what I do not really know is how can this be done when implementing a kernel module. Any answer that mentions or redirects to some real examples would be rather helpful.

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail: do you want to change affinity of some existing thread or spawn a new thread with a given affinity from your kernel module? What are you trying to accomplish this way? This information may help the experts here to give you answers.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. What I want to do is to establish two threads on different cores each, so that I can make some measurements about the cache coherency problem. To make my measurements precise I need to add inlined assembly but I also have to disable preemption. To do so, I have to have a linux kernel module for the task. However, for such a module the libc library is invisible and for this reason I want to see which function changes the affinity of THREAD, no of a PROCESS in a LKM. I hope this is clear now...

Answer (score 3):

You should use *kthreads*, which stands for *kernel threads*. To create such on specified cpu, you should invoke `kthread_create_on_cpu()`. It is defined in `include/linux/kthread.h`. Thread will be created in sleep state, so you should call `wake_up_process()` on it. That's all.

You can get one example of using kthreads in my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022958/why-does-this-code-deadlock/18028228#18028228) question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use kthread_bind() function.